# What is difference between prerequest, postrequest, preWebtest, and postWebTest?

Tags: azure-devops

Couldn't find any documentation on MSDN.

This is on VSTS2019

No Codes

No output

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean [web test plugin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.webtesting.webtestplugin?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=visualstudiosdk-2017&viewFallbackFrom=visualstudiosdk-2019). They are event handlers that will be trigger before, after requesting, before after testting.